# i did coding in jsp page but next page it gives null value

Tags: java, image, jsp, servlets

```
package com.gtlsoftware;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024*2, // 2MB
maxFileSize=1024*1024*10,      // 10MB
maxRequestSize=1024*1024*50)   // 50MB
public class MenuServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MenuServlet()
    {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        Connection con;
        ResultSet rs;
        PreparedStatement  pst;
        //INSERT INTO DATABASE  

            PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
            pw.print("hello");
            String name=request.getParameter("name");

             pw.println(name);

             System.out.println(name);
             String description = request.getParameter("description"); 
             String image = request.getParameter("image");
             String category=request.getParameter("category");
             String unit=request.getParameter("unit");
             String units=request.getParameter("units");
             String price=request.getParameter("price");

             byte[] b=null;

        try
          {
            con=MyConnection.getConnection();
            DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

             ServletFileUpload sfu = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
             List items = sfu.parseRequest(request);

             Iterator iter = items.iterator();

             while (iter.hasNext()) 
             {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
                if (!item.isFormField()) 
                {
                     b = item.get();
                 }
             }
            pst=con.prepareStatement("insert into menu(menu_name,description,image,category,unit,units,price) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            pst.setString(1, name);
            pst.setString(2, description);
            pst.setBytes(3,b);
            pst.setString(4, category);
            pst.setString(5, unit);
            pst.setString(6,units);
            pst.setString(7,price);
            pst.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("inserted successfully");
        } 
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (FileUploadException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            // TODO: handle exception
        }


    }

}
```

I did coding image is inserted .but when i am use  in form enctype="multipart/form-data then null values goes to next page i also add commons logging and file upload jar and if i remove enctype then value inserts but image not insert am taking image in longblob

and jsp page is menu.jsp

```
<body>
    <center>
        <div>
        <table border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="5" style="text-align: left">
            <tr>
                <td><%@ include file="header.jsp" %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="main_div">
                    <fieldset>
                            <form name="menuFrm"  action="MenuServlet" method="post" onsubmit="reurn(validate())" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                                <table cellspacing="7" cellpadding="2" align="center" border="0" style="font-family: sans-serif;font-weight: normal;font-size: medium"> 
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" style="background-color: black;color: white;font-family: Centaur;font-size: 20px;text-align: center;">
                                        <h4>Menu</h4>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Menu Id :</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="menuId" id="MenuId" value="<%=++cnt %>" tabindex="1" size="30%" placeholder="enter menu name"></td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Name  :</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="hdsuidd" tabindex="1" size="30%" placeholder="enter menu name"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Description:</td>
                                    <td><textarea rows="6" cols="30" name="description" size="30%" tabindex="4" id="description" size="30%" placeholder="enter description"></textarea></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>Image:</td>
                                    <td><input type="file" class="txtset" id="image" name="image" tabindex="5"/></td>
                                    </form>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Category:</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select id="category" class="txtset" name="category">
                                            <option selected="selected">select category</option>
                                            <option value="veg">Veg</option>
                                            <option value="non-veg">Non-Veg</option>
                                        </select>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Units:</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="unit" id="unit" class="txtset" tabindex="6" width="10%" onkeyup="myNum()"/>
                                        <select id="units" name="units">
                                            <option selected="selected">select units</option>
                                            <option value="kg">KG</option>
                                            <option value="gram">GRAM</option>
                                            <option value="unit">Unit</option>
                                        </select>


                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Price:</td>
                                    <td><input type="text"  name="price" class="txtset" id="price"  onkeyup="myNum()" tabindex="7" width="30%" height="10%">&nbsp;&nbsp;/-Rs.</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td><font color='white'> <DIV id="une" style="background-color: red;font-weight: bold;"> </DIV> </font></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="submit" value="Add"  style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size: large;text-align: center;width"  onclick="valid();check()"/></td>
                                    <td><input type="reset" value="Cancel" style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size: large;text-align: center;width" onclick="reset()"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <br>
                                        <br>
                                            <a href="edit.jsp" style="color: black;text-align:center;font-family: Centaur;font-size: 20px;">
                                                <u>Edit</u></a>
                                            &nbsp;   &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                            <a href="update.jsp" style="color: black;text-align:center;font-family: Centaur;font-size: 20px;">
                                            <u>Update</u></a>
                                            &nbsp;   &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                            <a href="delete.jsp" style="color: black;text-align:center;font-family: Centaur;font-size: 20px";>
                                            <u>Delete</u></a>
                                            &nbsp;   &nbsp; &nbsp;

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>


                        </form>
                            <%
                                con.close();
                            %>

                    </fieldset>
                    </div>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%@ include file="footer.jsp" %></td>
            </tr>   
        </table>
        </div>
    </center>




</body>
```

Comment: please give me some suggestion what i have to do

Answer (score -1):

You are using wrong code to receive and insert image in your servlet. Image is always send as multipart data to a servlet so use of `form enctype="multipart/form-data` is correct. But in your servlet you are receiving image as parameter which is wrong. Image should be received as part data like this:-

```
Part filePart=request.getPart("image");
```

Then we retrieve file path from part data like this :-

```
String filePath = filePart.getSubmittedFileName();
```

After we retrieve image file from path and then convert it to File input stream so it can be inserted as binary data :-

```
File image = new File(filePath);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(image);
```

After it the correct statement to insert image is this :-

```
pst.setBinaryStream (3, fis, (int) image.length() );
```

Here 3 is the column value of longblob data in your table. After these modifications in your servlet, I am sure all your form data will be inserted successfully in your database. And yes,  remove these following lines from your code :-

```
pw.print("hello");
pw.println(name);
System.out.println("inserted successfully");
```

Create two Html pages named SuccessPage.html and FailurePage.html which print Success and failure messages to console and code last line of insert operation like this :-

```
int rowCount=pst.executeUpdate();
if(rowCount>0){
            response.sendRedirect("SuccessPage.jsp");
        }
        else{
            response.sendRedirect("FailurePage.jsp");
        }
```

P.S. : Replace your mulitpart config line :-

```
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024*2, // 2MB
maxFileSize=1024*1024*10,      // 10MB
maxRequestSize=1024*1024*50)   // 50MB
```

by this :-

```
@MultipartConfig(location="/tmp", fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024*2, maxFileSize=1024*1024*10, maxRequestSize=1024*1024*50)
```

If this answer helps you, accept it by clicking right mark on top left corner of it. If not, let me know. All the best :) 
Here is your modified JSP :-

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
        <div>
        <table border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="5" style="text-align: left">
            <%--<tr>
                <td><%@ include file="header.jsp" %></td>
            </tr>--%>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="main_div">
                    <fieldset>
                            <form name="menuFrm"  action="SOQ52" method="post" onsubmit="reurn(validate())" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                                <table cellspacing="7" cellpadding="2" align="center" border="0" style="font-family: sans-serif;font-weight: normal;font-size: medium"> 
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" style="background-color: black;color: white;font-family: Centaur;font-size: 20px;text-align: center;">
                                        <h4>Menu</h4>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Menu Id :</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="menuId" id="MenuId"  tabindex="1" size="30%" placeholder="enter menu name"></td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Name  :</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" tabindex="1" size="30%" placeholder="enter menu name"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Description:</td>
                                    <td><textarea rows="6" cols="30" name="description" size="30%" tabindex="4" id="description" size="30%" placeholder="enter description"></textarea></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>Image:</td>
                                    <td><input type="file" class="txtset" id="image" name="image" tabindex="5"/></td>
                                    </form>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Category:</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select id="category" class="txtset" name="category">
                                            <option selected="selected">select category</option>
                                            <option value="veg">Veg</option>
                                            <option value="non-veg">Non-Veg</option>
                                        </select>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Units:</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="unit" id="unit" class="txtset" tabindex="6" width="10%" onkeyup="myNum()"/>
                                        <select id="units" name="units">
                                            <option selected="selected">select units</option>
                                            <option value="kg">KG</option>
                                            <option value="gram">GRAM</option>
                                            <option value="unit">Unit</option>
                                        </select>


                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Price:</td>
                                    <td><input type="text"  name="price" class="txtset" id="price"  onkeyup="myNum()" tabindex="7" width="30%" height="10%">&nbsp;&nbsp;/-Rs.</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td><font color='white'> <DIV id="une" style="background-color: red;font-weight: bold;"> </DIV> </font></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="submit" value="Add"  style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size: large;text-align: center;width"  onclick="valid();check()"/></td>
                                    <td><input type="reset" value="Cancel" style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size: large;text-align: center;width" onclick="reset()"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <br>
                                        <br>
                                            <a href="edit.jsp" style="color: black;text-align:center;font-family: Centaur;font-size: 20px;">
                                                <u>Edit</u></a>
                                            &nbsp;   &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                            <a href="update.jsp" style="color: black;text-align:center;font-family: Centaur;font-size: 20px;">
                                            <u>Update</u></a>
                                            &nbsp;   &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                            <a href="delete.jsp" style="color: black;text-align:center;font-family: Centaur;font-size: 20px";>
                                            <u>Delete</u></a>
                                            &nbsp;   &nbsp; &nbsp;

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>


                        </form>

                    </fieldset>
                    </div>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <%--<tr>
                <td><%@ include file="footer.jsp" %></td>
            </tr>--%>   
        </table>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is your servlet :-

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
//import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
//import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
//import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
//import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024*2, // 2MB
maxFileSize=1024*1024*10,      // 10MB
maxRequestSize=1024*1024*50)   // 50MB
public class SOQ52 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        //Connection con;
        ResultSet rs;
        PreparedStatement  pst;
        //INSERT INTO DATABASE  

            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
            //pw.print("hello");
            String name=request.getParameter("name");

             //pw.println(name);

             System.out.println(name);
             String description = request.getParameter("description"); 
             //String image = request.getParameter("image");
             String category=request.getParameter("category");
             String unit=request.getParameter("unit");
             String units=request.getParameter("units");
             String price=request.getParameter("price");

             //byte[] b=null;

             Part filePart=request.getPart("image");
             String filePath = filePart.getSubmittedFileName();
             File image = new File(filePath);
             FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(image); 
        /*     
        try
          {
            //con=MyConnection.getConnection();
            //DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

             //ServletFileUpload sfu = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
             //List items = sfu.parseRequest(request);

             //Iterator iter = items.iterator();

             //while (iter.hasNext()) 
             {
                //FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
                //if (!item.isFormField()) 
                {
                     //b = item.get();
                 }
             }
            pst=con.prepareStatement("insert into menu(menu_name,description,image,category,unit,units,price) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            pst.setString(1, name);
            pst.setString(2, description);
            pst.setBytes(3,b);
            pst.setString(4, category);
            pst.setString(5, unit);
            pst.setString(6,units);
            pst.setString(7,price);
            pst.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("inserted successfully");
        } 
        //catch (SQLException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //catch (FileUploadException e)
        {
            //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            // TODO: handle exception
        }*/

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try {
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet TestServlet</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1> Name : " +name+"</h1>");
            out.println("<h1> Desc : " +description+"</h1>");
            out.println("<h1> Category : " +category+"</h1>");
            out.println("<h1> Unit : " +unit+"</h1>");
            out.println("<h1> Units : " +units+"</h1>");
            out.println("<h1> Price : " +price+"</h1>");
            out.println("<h1> Image filePath : " +filePath+"</h1>");
            out.print("");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }catch(Exception ex){

        }    

    }

}
```

Run it and check it yourself. Nothing is giving null.

Comment: actually i did same as you given me solution but still it gives me null value while calling in servlet name=null

Comment: @SwatiDhamdhere: Only name is null or all the other parameters are null ?

Comment: if you have time please do the same code and send meits urgent

Comment: I ran your code and checked it. Nothing is giving null. You can check it in my modified answer.